# How to use replace and json.dumps with escape character?

Tags: python, json, replace

I have an url like `stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334`.
This is a for cgminer conf. And I need convert it to format `stratum+tcp:\/\/stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334`and after convert to JSON

When I try to use .replace function I got

```
In [46]: {'url': url1.replace('/','\/')}
Out[46]: {'url': 'stratum+tcp:\\/\\/stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334'}
```

and json.dumps function add more characters

```
In [47]: json.dumps({'url': url1.replace('/','\/')})
Out[47]: '{"url": "stratum+tcp:\\\\/\\\\/stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334"}'
```

I can't understand how I can make json with url's format that I need

```
{'url': 'stratum+tcp:\/\/stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do any character replacement.

```py
json.dumps({'url': 'stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334'})
```

outputs

```
'{"url": "stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334"}'
```

which is perfectly valid JSON. Done.